# gpslogger android studio epic fail

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been looking at GPSLOGGER - https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger/ - an opensource GPS tracking app for android.

Trying to run it on Android Studio I got the following errors:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\gpslogger-master\gpslogger\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fil\values-fil.xml:145: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
"Ang app na ito ay nangangailangan ng iba't-ibang permiso upang gumana ng wasto. <br /><b>Lokasyon ng aparato</b> - Ang permisong ito ay papayag sa pagbasa ng datos ng lokasyon galing sa mga tore ng cell at sa GPS hardware ng aparato. <br /><b>Mga larawan, media, files</b> - Ang permisong ito ay papayag sa pagsulat ng files ng tala at files ng pagsusuri sa imbakan, at pagbasa mula sa isang listahan ng mga files para sa pag-upload o pagbahagi. Ang app na ito ay hindi mag-access ng iyong mga larawan o media. <br /><b>I-access ang iyong mga kontak</b> - Kung gumagamit ng kapakinabangan ng Google Drive, ang permisong ito ay papayag sa paglista ng mga Google accounts na rehistrado sa aparatong ito. Ang iyong listahan ng mga kontak ay hindi ina-access ng app na ito.<br />
".
C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\gpslogger-master\gpslogger\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fil\values-fil.xml:145: error: not a valid string.

Command: C:\Users\Marco\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\29325d8080ba4e20f4efa9431f6b5dfb\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\gpslogger-master\gpslogger\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\gpslogger-master\gpslogger\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fil\values-fil.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1
```

I am now really stuck. Can anyone help me figure it out?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ' symbol in the string in values-fil.xml.  The problem is in their code, not what you're doing.

Comment: The problem is: I cant modify the file. On make, the compiler changes back to the original file.

Comment: You're modifying it in the wrong place. Modify the actual language file, not the R file